# Nuget can't read AssemblyInfo.cs if called with full path

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-devops

If calling `nuget pack c:\source\project1\project.nuspec` within the c:\soruce\project1 folder can't it read the details from AssemblyInfo.cs.
Visual Studio Team Services (former Visual Studio Online) is doing it that way and there for is it not possible to use a wildcard version number read from AssemblyInfo.cs.
There don't seem to be any option in Nuget to set a working folder.

The idea is to have nightly builds with the version increment on the build number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create the nuget package file from the project file directly via:

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj
```

The generated package is named base on the version number in AssemblyInfo.cs.

Comment: It is controlled by VSTS so it is not an option. I ended up using PowerShell instead to set the version in the .nuspec file.